# Launching Click Once Application - File Not Found

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have a basic service that will be used to run a ClickOnce application every x minutes, however when i run Process.Start() i am receiving an exception that the file cannot be found.

Code

```
        private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        WriteToFile("Timer ticked");
        CheckProcess(GetProcessName());
    }

    public void CheckProcess(string ProcessName)
    {

        WriteToFile(ProcessName);

        try
        {
            Process.Start(ProcessName);
            WriteToFile("It ran");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteToFile(ex.ToString());
        }

    }

    public string GetProcessName()
    {
        string ProcessName = string.Concat("%AppData%\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\", PublisherName, "\\", ProductName, ".appref-ms");
        return ProcessName;
    }
```

The error i receive is:

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\PubName\ProdName.appref-ms
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String fileName)
```

If i run the ProcessName retrieved in explorer then the application launches successfully.  Value of ProcessName is :

C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\PubName\ProdName.appref-ms

Is there something i am missing in order to start the file?

Comment: Is your Project a Windows Service ?

Comment: Yes the project the code is from above is a Windows Service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Services are the programs which will runs even before a user logged into it's Account. This is Windows Service purpose, and by this definition you haven't access to specific User Environment Variables (Like %AppData%) because **you aren't in the User Session** so your address will be translated to something **Odd** if you write it into a .txt you will see the result.

Windows Services (By your definitions) will run by LocalSystem, LocalService or NetworkService. Go to TaskManager->Services->Open Services and watch `Log On As` Column.

So you must use a general path which be access-able through your service.

Most terrifying solution is to force your Service to wait for a user login and impersonate his token.

I will Prefer to choose a better place.

There is a way to debug and see your Service bugs (In **UserSession**) in VisualStudio.
Change your Program.cs to something like:

```
static void Main()
{
#if DEBUG
        var MainService = new MainService();
        MainService.OnDebug();

#else

        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
        {
            new MainService()
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
#endif
}
```

and Add OnDebug function to your Service:

```
 public void OnDebug()
 {
    OnStart(null);
 }
```

if you debug your project in this way you will see that your service is working As Expected !!!

Comment: I managed to get this to run the process by getting the logged on user and building the app data path so the service can access, but the app doesn't open.  The process is running in task manager but the app doesn't appear.

Comment: Windows Service is run on a different session. if your app is a Windows Form or something visual; you cant see it on your desktop. actually your Desktop is a part of your Session so, when you call a Process under a Windows Service it will be executed as a System Session. if you are sure about the new Path that you set for the process; please check Task Manager Process tab and check "Show Process From All Users" to see all running processes.